# Advantage of fortress becoming capital

Tags: dwarf-fortress

It's my understanding that when the Monarch arrives, the fortress becomes the civilization's capital. Hence I stop getting dwarven liaisons (which would mean I would stop getting dwarven caravans, that provide me with some necessary resources not available in my embark location).

The wiki is also amiss on what happens to said civilization when the fortress eventually crumbles. What I want to know is:

- Does receiving the Monarch or becoming the capital provide any tangible (economical, military, social) advantage?
- What happens after the fortress ends (or when the Monarch dies)? Does the civilization keep going?

Comment: You still get caravans, it just means you don't have a chance to negotiate for specific stuff with the liason anymore.

Comment: @Shadur thanks for clearing that up, as the info on the wiki is fuzzy in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive a monarch and their entourage of **Elite Fighters** with +5 legendary skill in their weapon of choice. Accomplished skills in the other fighting traits, and the *I don't care about anything anymore* attitude. This King or Queen may also be a vampire, as is somewhat common for vampires that go undetected in a civilization.

Nothing happens if the Monarch dies, and yes your civilization will never stop going until all the **fun** has been had.